# Android studio: why image shown in design disapears in run time?

Tags: android, image, android-studio

Images shown in Android studio disapear in the emulator :
More than words, you can see thus [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qYs5f.png) explicit:

Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/signorGrey">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logoSignor"
        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="77dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/iconpetit2929"
        android:gravity="start|center_vertical"
        android:background="@color/signorBlue"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:contentDescription="@string/logosignor"/>
```

Do you know why ?

Comment: please post your code

Comment: Most likely the path to the image is develop-only. (On Windows a file path is case insensitive if not packed in a jar file.)

Comment: user496854: code added, tks!

Comment: Joop: ok tks, and do you know how to manage this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this problem before and as a solution, I solved the path of the photo by using src instead of srcCompat. I suggest you use it like this;

```
<ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/logoSignor"
                    android:layout_width="65dp"
                    android:layout_height="77dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/iconpetit2929"
                    android:gravity="start|center_vertical"
                    android:background="@color/signorBlue"
                    android:visibility="visible"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/logosignor"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your logcat you maybe getting some error like "bitmap too large" if that so your image can not be implemented try to change the width and height of image

Comment: Hi Saloni, unfortunatly no "bitmap too large" in the logcat

Comment: use android:src instead of app:srcCompat